Problem with navigate method within a function
I can't get the navigate method of the client object of rsDriver to work inside a function.
My sandbox is the Quotes to scrape website: http://quotes.toscrape.com/
My libraries and global variables are:
library(RSelenium)
library(httr)

rD <- rsDriver(port = 4442L, browser="firefox", chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

start_url <- "https://quotes.toscrape.com/"
quotes <- list()
authors <- list()


and I launch my script with:
get_quotes(start_url)

Here's my main function get_quotes(), which takes an url as parameter.
get_quotes <- function(page_url) {
  print(paste("Processing  ", page_url))
  # current page
  new_quotes <- lapply(get_quotes_elements(page_url), get_quote)
  quotes <<- append(quotes, new_quotes)
  # Find next page
  next_quotes_page_url <- get_next_quotes_page_url()
  if (!is.null(next_quotes_page_url)) {
    print(paste("next page url =  ", next_quotes_page_url))
    remDr$navigate(next_quotes_page_url)
    get_quotes(next_quotes_page_url)
  }
}

I use a lapply loop to extract quotes: for each HTML element of class .quote found on the page with the function get_quotes_elements()
get_quotes_elements <- function(page_url) {
  remDr$navigate(page_url)
  quotes_elements <- remDr$findElements("css selector", ".quote")
  return(quotes_elements)
}

, I execute the get_quote() function.
get_quote <- function(quote_element) {
  quote <- list()
  quote_text <- quote_element$findChildElement("css selector", ".text")$getElementText()
  quote_author <- quote_element$findChildElement("css selector", ".author")$getElementText()
  quote_tags_elements <- quote_element$findChildElements("css selector", ".tag")
  quote_tags <- list(unlist(lapply(quote_tags_elements, function(quote_tag){
    quote_tag$getElementText()
  })))
  quote['author'] <- quote_author
  quote['quote'] <- quote_text
  quote['tags'] <- quote_tags
  # Comment the 4 next lines to scrap only the quotes without the authors
  author_page_url <- quote_element$findChildElement("css selector", "a[href*='/author/']")$getElementAttribute("href")
  print(paste("  author url found :", author_page_url))
  remDr$navigate(author_page_url)
  author <- get_author(author_page_url)
  
  return(quote)
}

Then I search for other quotes pages using get_next_quotes_page_url()
get_next_quotes_page_url <- function() {
  next_button_element <- remDr$findElements("css selector", ".next a")
  next_quotes_page_url <- NULL
  if(length(next_button_element) > 0) {
    next_quotes_page_url <- unlist(lapply(next_button_element, function(next_page){
      next_page$getElementAttribute("href")
    }))
  }
  return(next_quotes_page_url)
}

, if so, I call the navigate() method, then execute get_quotes(), and so on for as long as there is a next page quotation link.
Everything works perfectly if I limit the script to extract quotes.
The problem arises when, inside get_quote(), I retrieve the link to the quote author's description and try to extract the author's information with get_author function:
get_author <- function(author_page_url) {
  print(paste("  processing scraping of : ", author_page_url))
  author_name = remDr$findElement("css selector", ".author-title")$getElementText()
  print(paste("  author name  ", author_name))
}

The navigation to the author's page doesn't work, which raises an Unable to locate element: .author-title error, which is consistent since I'm not on the right page.
I suspect an asynchronization problem, but I don't know enough about R and RSelenium to be sure.
